# Shortband for switch..case doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am clueless why this piece of code doesn't work:

```
switch (Category.getValue()) {
    case 1: () => { for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) OptionSet.addOption(options[i]); }; break;
    default: () => { OptionSet.clearOptions(); }; break;
}
```

It hits `case 1:`, but then instead of doing loop it just quits switch statement.

Comment: You define functions but never run them. I don't understand why you'd want to use functions here at all.

Comment: @Juhana, actually I wouldn't. But I am looking for making my code as simple as it can be. And I am new to js, so I don't know any good literature about shortbands to pick up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code `() => {}` You are essentially defining an anonymous function without assigning or calling it.  You can remove that part from the code and it will work.  [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/n3b2zgo5/)

Comment: Works perfect, Thank you.
Could I ask if you know any good reference about anonymous functions and its use cases?

Comment: This looks like a decent place to start: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions -- Just note the syntax you use `() => {}` is just shorthand for the full `function () {}` declaration

Comment: I know this. But I supposed my func to be called anyway.

Comment: For an anonymous function to be called it has to be followed by `()`, in your case you could wrap the declaration in parens and call it immediately as well, in this way `(() => { })()`.  However, there's little practical reason to do this unless the inner function needs closure for some reason.